# Rails out of memory issue ( heroku R14 )

Tags: ruby, heroku, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running an RoR app no heroku which rapidly takes the available 512 Mb. I'm using puma (4.3.5) .

I've followe the tutorials [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use#memory-leaks) and [the derailed benchmarks on local machine](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks). The **perf:mem_over_time** and benchmarks on local never raise any issues. What is astounding is the fact that no matter what, the memory on local machine does not increase whereas when app is deployed on heroku, it steadily increases.

Any ideas on how to debug the problem on heroku? Running the derailed benchmarks is not possible on heroky since it complains that it cannot connect to postgres server ( *User does not have CONNECT privilege.*)

Comment: have you tried running production locally? `rails s -e production` and point it to your local db. What gems are you using in production that aren't being used locally?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem seemed to be an obvious one : The number of workers on prod was set to 5. Each one take on average 80Mb, to start with, so just a minor increase in memory, triggere R14 not enough memory. I've reduced it to 2 workers and it' fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to switch to jemalloc for memory allocation. https://prathamesh.tech/2021/05/23/adding-jemalloc-to-rails-apps-on-heroku/ may be useful as well.

It allows your RAM usage to go back down (via freeing up memory) to a degree over time (unlike the default, which only goes up over time). Thus reducing RAM usage.